# Prevent go build from overwriting version in go.mod

Tags: go, module, dependencies

I have a go module that imports project foo. foo's latest tag says v1.4

when i do a `go build` in my project, it updates go.mod to say

```
module github.com/myid/mymod

require (
   github.com/myid/foo v1.4
)
```

I want it to use the master branch instead of v1.4 tag...so i did a 
`go get github.com/myid/foo@master` and it downloaded the master branch in pkg and updated go.mod to say

```
require (
    github.com/myid/foo v1-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX
)
```

I verify that the hash is the same as master

but when i do `go build` again, it gets updated back to the latest tag.

how do i get it to use the master branch and not switch back to v1.4?

Thanks

Comment: See here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-control-when-gomod-gets-updated-and-when-the-go-tools-use-the-network-to-satisfy-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Necro answer for anyone stumbling across this:

As of go `1.16` modules are no longer automatically bumped when using `go build` (etc..)

See: https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command

Answer (score 0):

The `go` command automatically resolves non-canonical [semantic versions](https://semver.org) to canonical versions or [pseudo-versions](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions).

`v1.4` is not a canonical semantic version.